# Regex for words formed with specific characters

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex to match words formed with specific characters without repeating any character: Example, for a b c and d, how to specify a regex to match those strings:

bdca (match)
adb (match)
abcg (fail)
aab (fail)
I tried with ^[abcd]{1,4}$ but it accepts repeated characters (last example).

Please any help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this regex based on negative lookahead:

```
^(?:([abcd])(?!.*\1)){1,4}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mZ4rR9/1)

**Breakup:**

```
^            Line start
(?:          Start non-capturing group
  ([abcd])   Match a or b or c or d and group it 
  (?!.*\1)   Negative lookahead to fail the match if same grouped char is ahead
){1,4}       1 to 4 occurrences of non-capturing group
$            Line end
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96816/discussion-between-anubhava-and-iouhammi).